# Different types in debugger when parsing JSON Dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, casting, nsdictionary

I'm saving a JSON array as 
    `var ingredients: [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]`

The JSON array has dictionaries that have keys that are strings, and values that can be Int or String.

I'm then trying to parse my Array of Dictionaries but I’m seeing some strange results in the debugger. 
When the value for "serving_count" is “0.5” the debugger says it’s a _NSCFNumber, but when the value is “1.0” it says it’s a _NSCFString. I have no idea why it would choose number when the JSON is clearly a string as seen below. 
Thank you

```
{
 "serving_count" = "1.0";
}
{
 "serving_count" = "0.5";  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The debugger output

```
{
 "serving_count" = "1.0";
}
{
 "serving_count" = "0.5";  
}
```

doesn't tell much about the data types. It's just how dictionaries are printed to the console. If you want to see the actual type in the NSDictionary, try printing

```
NSStringFromClass(ingredient.valueForKey("serving_count").dynamicType)
```

to check the actual types.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for responding. I updated my question to be more clear I hope. I also am no longer using a NSDictionary and instead am using an Array of Dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, in the debugger when I print out the JSON all the serving_counts were surrounded by double quotes. However, when I load up the JSON outside of Xcode, I can clearly see the issue. The service is sending some values as strings and some are numbers!

```
        {

            "serving_count": "1.0", 

        }, 
        {

            "serving_count": 0.5, 
          }
```